# Substitute variable value to command in python

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo, database-backups

I am trying to write a simple python script to collect certain command outputs from mongodb, as part of validating the database before and after backup.

Below is the script.

```
import pymongo
import json
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',username='admin',password='admin')
db = client['mydb']
collections = list(db.list_collection_names())
for i in collections:
  print(db.$i.estimated_document_count())
```

All the collections are stored in the list called collections and I want to run it in for loop so that I can get document count in each collection. I know the last print statement here is wrong. How to get it right? I want $i to substitute the collection name during each iteration so that I can get the document count of that collection.

When I run "print(db.audit.estimated_document_count())" it gives me the document count in audit collection. But how to iterate through the list in for loop and substitute the value of i in the command?

Also, for validating backup/restore is there any other commands that I should run against database to verify backup/restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a computed value as an identifier in at "dot" expression, at least not without resorting to dirty tricks.

What you *can* do, is to find some other mechanism for getting a collection given its name. According to the [tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-collection) and [API reference](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html), you can use `db['foo']` instead of `db.foo`.

Comment: Turned out to be simple. Thanks a lot.